What webcam compatible video recording software is available for Linux?
I need some basic easy to setup video recording software that will record fine with the webcam and the microphone.
I have seen OBS mentioned and I intend to try it out but it looks to advanced and complicated?
Any other options for Linux?

What does "too advanced and complicated" mean? This question severly lacks details.
